# EF reload refrences

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am adding new entity to the context and I would like populate all its references collections once the add is done. Issue is, I am reading the same entity from the context which I created during the add(), basically EF doesn't go to the DB. This is correct behaviour, but how do I get around it ?

```
    Repo().Add(newEntity);
    Repo().Reload(newEntity);
```

This reloads the entity from DB however I am not getting the references (FK relations). I have found how to load the reference, however I would need a generic way how to load all the references for any entity.

```
var entry = Context.Entry(entity);
entry.Reference("ReferenceName").Load();
```

Is the above the correct approach or is there some other way ?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your repository code, I am guessing it's a lazy loading issue.

This site explains eager vs lazy loading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

You can either specify exactly what references you want to bring back by using the .Include() in your repo (good for long chains where you dont need everything).

```
context.Set<whateverType>.Include(t => t.(whatever you are referencing)).Where(t => t.id = id);
```

Or you can specify the context to use eager loading and bring back everything with your retrieval.

```
context.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, nice explanation. I have  this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false and I am getting everything in other scenarios. Just this add behaves differently. Because it is in the context it doesn't really go and reload again, therefore it doesn't reach the lazy vs eager issue, I am thinking.

Comment: Hm. Do you dispose your context after the add? Try disposing and re-instantiating the context in your reload method.